# Showing $m^*(A-E)=m^*(A)$ when $m^*(E)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I'm trying to show that $m^*(A-E)=m^*(A)$ when $m^*(E)=0$ where $m^*$ is the outer measure.

So my plan is to show that

$m^*(A-E) \geq m^*(A)$

and

$m^*(A-E) \leq m^*(A)$ (and this one is easy, because $A-E$ $\subset$ $A$)

I'm having a harder time showing $m^*(A-E) \geq m^*(A)$ 
. My strategy is to let $\epsilon>0$ and then to show that $m^*(A-\cup K)$ $> \epsilon + m^*(A)$ where $E \subset \cup K$. I might be on the wrong track here though. This measure theory stuff is hard, can any of you nerd genius's shed some light on this for me? Thanks!

Comment: can you use $m^{\star}(A\backslash E) +m^{\star}(E)\ge m^{\star}(A)$ ?

Comment: Mmmm, I'm going to go with no, unless we prove it.

Comment: @MichaelVaughan it should be clear that $A \subset (A \setminus E) \cup E$. Now use subadditivity of $m^*$.

Comment: I proved the subadditivity of the ([tag:outer-measure]) from scratch so that OP can use @orangeskid's idea.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the comment, use the subadditivity of the outer measure to finish the question.

$$m^{\star}(A \setminus E) = m^{\star}(A \setminus E) +m^{\star}(E)\ge m^{\star}(A) \implies m^{\star}(A \setminus E) = m^{\star}(A)$$

---

To prove the subadditivity of the outer measure, let $\epsilon > 0$, and $A, B$ be two subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ having countable open interval covers $(I_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $(J_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ respectively so that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_i) < m^{\star}(A) + \frac\epsilon2$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \ell(J_j) < m^{\star}(B) + \frac\epsilon2$.  (Such covers exist since $m^\star$ is the *infimum* of the sum of length of covering open intervals.)

Clearly, $\{(I_i)_{i=1}^{\infty},(J_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}\}$ covers $A \cup B$, and the sum of length of covering open intervals

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_i) + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \ell(J_j) < m^{\star}(A) + m^{\star}(B) + \epsilon$$

To finish the proof, on the LHS, take infimum over all countable open interval covers for $A \cup B$ so that $m^\star(A\cup B)$ appears on the LHS.

$$m^\star(A\cup B) < m^{\star}(A) + m^{\star}(B) + \epsilon$$

Since the choice of $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that

$$m^\star(A\cup B) \le m^{\star}(A) + m^{\star}(B).$$

Comment: Just an observation,  infimum over finite covers gives the Jordan outer measure, over countable covers gives the Lebesgue outer measure, Both are subadditive,

Comment: @orangeskid Oh sorry.  I meant Lebesgue outer measure.  I'm going to correct this.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 -  Just curious (since I'm new to measure theory), why can we say " since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we can conclude that $m^\star(A\cup B) \le m^{\star}(A) + m^{\star}(B)".$ Wouldn't that mean $\epsilon = 0$ on the right hand side? Again, i'm not criticizing, i'm just curious as to why we can do this.

Comment: @TaylorRendon I appreciate your question.  Looking back, when I put $A$, $B$ and $\epsilon$ in one sentence, I didn't make it clear than these three variables exist independently: each of $A$, $B$ and $\epsilon$ exists on its own.  However, $(I_i)_i$ and $(J_j)_j$ depend on $A$, $B$ and $\epsilon$.   A more elementary version of your problem having a proof by contradiction : if a constant $a$ satisfies $a < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, show that $a \le 0$.